# CSS: frame is in foreground

Tags: css

I have a problem with my image animation frame. The easiest way to show my problem is just showing my website :-).
http://www.nouvelle-moi.be/
put your browser in a window and scroll down. You'll see that the image slides over the header. How can I resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Truth is, the Facebook buttons are floating over your header as well. The `z-index` property is designed for you to explicitly specify which element supersedes the other. By setting the `z-index` to something like 999 the header will remain on top of all other elements,

By adding this CSS to your website the header will remain on top of the other elements

```
#header {
z-index: 999;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `z-index` css property of the header to 10. That should solve your issue.

Comment: Note that this requires the `position` rule to be explicitly set.

Comment: Does it? Interesting. In Firebug all I had to do was add the `z-index` and it fixed it.

Comment: Not all browsers will render it properly without a `position` rule being set. IE is an example.